# How to use covariates in rddtools rdd_reg_lm function?

Tags: r, rdd, causality

I am trying to run a parametric RD regression using the rddtools R package. However, the package documentation is not very clear to me.

**First:** the function to define an RD object is:
`rdd_data(y, x, covar, cutpoint, z, labels, data)`

where covar, in the help file, means only *"Exogeneous variables"* . But what type? A data frame? A list?

**Second:** The function rdd_reg_lm again demands informing covariates in this way:

```
rdd_reg_lm(rdd_object, covariates = NULL, order = 1, bw = NULL,
  slope = c("separate", "same"), covar.opt = list(strategy = c("include",
  "residual"), slope = c("same", "separate"), bw = NULL),
  covar.strat = c("include", "residual"), weights)
```

Where, according to the help file, the covariates argument means simply *"Formula to include covariates"*. Again, it is not clear to me what is exactly the correct way of applying these covariates.

Moreover, is it possible to include multiple covariates in this function `rdd_data()` and `rdd_reg_lm()`?

I appreciate some help here. I have already read the help and vignette files again and again, searched in many blogs and still nothing.

I have already checked this topic below

[How to include a linear trend in a regression discontinuity design using rddtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316532/how-to-include-a-linear-trend-in-a-regression-discontinuity-design-using-rddtool)

which showed me the following example:

```
rd.medic <- rdd_data(y = er ,x = ageyrs, covar = ageyrs, cutpoint=65, data = medicare)

rd.reg <- rdd_reg_lm(rdd_object=rd.medic, covariates = 'ageyrs', slope =
("same"), covar.opt = list("include"))
```

Even so, the syntax is still not clear to me, as I am trying to add multiple covariates without success

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data frame with your covariates and then include it in rdd_data.

```
covariates<-data.frame(z1=ageyrs, z2=ageyrs2)

rd.medic <- rdd_data(y = er ,x = ageyrs, covar = covariates, cutpoint=65, data = medicare)

rd.reg <- rdd_reg_lm(rdd_object=rd.medic, covariates =TRUE, slope =("same"))
```